# Can't download files using HTTPS

Tags: 16.04, https

I recently wanted to install sublime text, and found a way to download the installer (using a PPA), the installer runs and downloads the actual package through HTTPS, it stays running for about 15 minutes and then a "Time out" appears, I've tried to test downloading the package manually using wget, and wget does the same thing, first it tries to connect to server, then the connection succeeds, after that nothing happens until the "Time out" message appears again, obviously I'm not able to download files over HTTPS but I CAN access websites using HTTPS. Any suggestions?

Here's the output in terminal when installing the package:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  sublime-text-installer
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 38 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/9,482 B of archives.
After this operation, 26.6 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package sublime-text-installer.
(Reading database ... 242647 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../sublime-text-installer_3114-2~webupd8~0_all.deb ...
Downloading...
--2016-08-13 14:34:55--  https://download.sublimetext.com/sublime_text_3_build_3114_x64.tar.bz2
Resolving download.sublimetext.com (download.sublimetext.com)... 104.236.0.104
Connecting to download.sublimetext.com (download.sublimetext.com)|104.236.0.104|:443... connected.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
download failed
Download done.
Removing outdated cached downloads...
sha256sum mismatch sublime_text_3_build_3114_x64.tar.bz2
Sublime Text is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/sublime-text-installer_3114-2~webupd8~0_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/sublime-text-installer_3114-2~webupd8~0_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
W: Operation was interrupted before it could finish
```

Answer (score 0):

Install Sublime (v3) from [Webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/07/sublime-text-3-ubuntu-ppa-now-available.html) ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer
```

**OR**

Install Sublime (v2) from [Webupd8](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/sublime-text-2) ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-2
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text
```

Just tried out these `ppas`. Everything works fine.

Comment: I did that and that was the cause of the problem, now I can't install any package nor update because the sublime-text-installer is now incomplete and requires reinstallation, the problem is that the installer is downloaded just fine, but the actual package is not because of that https problem, how do I solve it?

Comment: @Kareem - Which one are you trying to install? v3 or v2

Comment: I'm installing v3

Comment: check the error code I've just attached to the question description.

Comment: @Kareem - The error may not at all related to `https` as I can download the application and install the software without any issues. To check if it really is the problem with `https` do `cd /tmp; wget https://download.sublimetext.com/sublime_text_3_build_3114_x64.tar.bz2; rm -rf sublime_text_3_build_3114_x64.tar.bz2`.

Comment: Still the same problem after executing your commands in terminal.

Comment: @Kareem - Do `check_certificate = off >> $HOME/.wgetrc` and then try again.

Comment: Well that .wgetrc file didn't exist so I created one in that directory, rebooted, and yet no luck in getting it to work :(
I also tried to download using this "wget -S --check-certificate=off LINK" and didn't work neither.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43910/discussion-between-raphael-and-kareem).